# macruby: Using ruby method as AXObserverCallback

Tags: ruby, cocoa

I trying to watch out for a text field to change, using `macruby`.

`AXObserverCreate` expects an `AXObserverCallback` as parameter.
**How can I pass a ruby function as a callback?**

My function in `AX.m`:

```
+ (AXError) addNotificationWithElement: (AXUIElementRef) element
             forEvent:(CFStringRef) event_type
             callback:(AXObserverCallback) acallback;
```

This is how I want to invoke this method:

`rb_main.rb`:

```
def my_callback *args
  p args
end

p AX.addNotificationWithElement ref,
                      forEvent:'AXValueChange',
                      callback: *** What to write here?***
```

What to pass to my `addNotificationWithElement` function that expects an `AXObserverCallback` as callback parameter?

For reference: [Apple documentation for `AXObserverCallback`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/AXUIElement_h/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AXObserverCallback)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass any `Proc` (or `lambda`) that takes the arguments given in Apple's documentation. In this case:

```
proc { |observer, element, notification, refcon| ... }
```

You could use the following in your example (i.e. if the callback is a method):

```
proc { |*args| my_callback *args }
```

I haven't tested it in cases where `AXObserverCallback` is required, but this seems to be the general pattern.